# java servlet compile error

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

1.i added the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_01\bin for java and C:\TOMCAT\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\lib for tomcat.

2.i have started startup.bat in C:\TOMCAT\apache-tomcat-7.0.55\bin and it works fine.

3.it displays in 8084 port(localhost:8084/).

4.i created a MyServlet.java file in Directory E.

5.i wanted to compile it through command line(javac MyServlet.java) bt errror comes.

i have tried and tried bt.. :( ..plz help me to fix it.

MyServlet.java code:

```
import javax.servlet.*; 
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class MyServlet extends  HttpServlet
{
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResposne response) 
                 throws ServletException
{
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("<html><body>");
out.println("<h1>Hello Readers</h1>");
out.println("</body></html>");
} 
}
```

and cmd errors:

```
E:\>javac MyServlet.java
MyServlet.java:1: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.*;
^
MyServlet.java:2: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.*;
^
MyServlet.java:7: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
                ^
MyServlet.java:8: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
                     ^
MyServlet.java:9: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
                     ^
MyServlet.java:10: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
                     ^
MyServlet.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol: class HttpServlet
public class MyServlet extends  HttpServlet
                            ^
MyServlet.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
location: class MyServlet
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResposne response)
              ^
MyServlet.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletResposne
location: class MyServlet
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResposne response)
                                         ^
MyServlet.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServletException
location: class MyServlet
                 throws ServletException
                        ^
10 errors
```

Comment: public **class** MyServlet...Voting to close.

Comment: I am following this http://www.studytonight.com/servlet/steps-to-create-servlet-using-tomcat-server.php

Comment: It's a simple typo. Learn Java before you jump into the Servlet API.

Comment: @user3751576 Also, where and why did you get `jdk_1.6.0_1`? Your tutorial has the typo in your question, but they're using Java 7. And why are you using a 32-bit Java on a 64-bit machine?

Comment: oh its a simple typo.tnx

Comment: So now you edited your question to something else...Look into what a `ClassNotFoundException` is.

Answer (score 1):

[Declaring Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html)

```
public class MyServlet extends  HttpServlet
```

instead of

```
public MyServlet extends  HttpServlet
```

Comment: hmm its a silly mistake bt why servlet class is not finding

Comment: Include the javaee.jar download from the link http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaeejar.htm

Answer (score 1):

you forget the keyword `class` when define a class, just put the `class` before the class name